# Importing eclipse android project into android studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I am trying to import an android project created in eclipse into android studio. This main project also refers to another library project in the same eclipse workspace. The folder structure is like this:

workspace\app1
workspace\lib1

When I import the main project into android studio, the library project is automatically imported as a sub-project (or shall we call it a module) within the main project. That's not what I want. The library project is shared by multiple apps I am maintaining. It should sit in parallel with other app projects in terms of folder structure. I wouldn't want it to go understand any particular app project.

Please help explain how I can make the library project stand its own and refer to the library project from other app projects in android project. I am fairly new to the gradle build system. So detailed instructions would be highly appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: check this http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html

Comment: Read up on gradle modules. If u need good example from github , go there n search on "glide" https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Answer (score 0):

Since you are importing in android studio, I assume you are moving to gradle build system. In your case , I think, it would be best to have a separate AS project for library. Use that project to generate a jar file and then import that jar using gradle build script in each project you want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sharing the same library across multiple, you can configure them as separate AS project and have "aar" file as output. (In your gradle you put>> apply plugin: 'android-library'). You then define them as dependency in your gradle file. (either through maven repo or putting it in your libs directory and defining it in your dependencies section). You can find more info at http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Library-projects

Comment: Yes. I already make it a separate library project. But I am still not clear how to refer to the library project from app project. I assume we have to add such a line into the file build.gradle in the app project.

dependencies {
    compile project(':libraries:lib1')
 }

However, android studio couldn't find lib1 when I attempt to build. How can I tell it the full path of the lib1? I used "../lib1" but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

You can use version control tool such as `git` to synchronize the library project in every main project. But you need to use a version control tool to manage all your projects first.

Answer (score 0):

Read [here](http://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/all-in-together-android-studio-gradle-and-robolectric/) on "AS Modules"

review 57.1.2 on ["common behavior"](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html)

Take a look at [a project](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) built on AS pattern of modules as libs used in eclipse (gradle.settings) pictured

all the includes are modules

[image]

maybe you can rethink the idea of how to get AS to work for you in reusing code....